# Jmeter login issue?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

So, I have understood the way our SSO based service is set up. Now I am trying to log in via J-meter. But when i try posting the user, pwd via param , I get nothing in return and the page goes back to the login page. What I am expecting a ID as a response. I have attached the screenshots . Would appreciate any help .[image]

The site has a form for username with name"j_username" and password "j_password" .

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan as `[no cookies]` is not something I would expect from the login flow
2. Second compare the request which JMeter is sending with the request which is being sent by the real browser. You can use either [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) on the browser side and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener on JMeter side or something external like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). The main idea is that if you send exactly the same request - you should get the same response
3. In addition to point 2 real users do the following:

   - Open Login Page
   - Perform Login

Your JMeter test should be following the same pattern, i.e. don't try to log in using a single request as you might be missing something important, i.e. a dynamic parameter which is being set on the previous page which might be i.e. a [CSRF Token](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Token_Based_Mitigation). You can record your test flow using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) for 2 times and compare recorded requests, if there will be differences - you will need to perform [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter) of the dynamic values, to wit extracting the dynamic parameter(s) from the previous response using a suitable JMeter [Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and saving it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and replacing recorded hard-coded value in the 2nd request with the variable from the previous step.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the reply, I solved it but now I have issue while trying to extract this ticket=ST-somechar via regex extractor. I been trying to use the expression (.*?) but i get no value. There is nothing after that ticket value.

Comment: Blind shot: use `(.*)`, however it's hard to say anything without seeing your response and regular expression extractor configuration.

Comment: I tried using that but I got null. So what I wish to extract isocation: h/j_spring_cas_security_check;jsessionid=some number;ticket=ST-some number with alphabets and -'s. My regex extractor is configured as : name:ticket, expression: Location:https://(.*) , Template $1$, Match o. I am checking the response headers.